# Nginx redirect for http and https

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to force HTTPS for incoming connections while also redirecting all requests to a certain url.

Desired result:

http://example.com -> https://example.com/dir

https://example.com -> https://example.com/dir

Here is what I believe should work but is saying there are too many redirects.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

   location / {
    return         301 https://$server_name/dir$request_uri;
   }

   location /dir {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Server that is listening to 443 port shouldn't redirect to itself (return 301 https://...)

Comment: How would I write the redirect to the /dir part then? Would I just drop the https?

Comment: Something like this should work - `rewrite ^((?!dir/)\S+)$ dir/$1 permanent;`. Not really sure about the regex though haven't tested it

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
      return 301 https://example.com/dir$request_uri; 
    }

    location /dir {
      ...
      ...
    }

}
```

Basically the idea is to keep both listen directive in the same server block. The above code is just an excerpt and you need to fill in the missing pieces.You can refer the return directive section of [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) link for more detail

EDIT: Updated the code with location block.

Comment: Unfortunately getting the same result. The returned URL looks like this:  https://example.com/dir/dir/dir/dir/dir/....and so on. Not sure if thats what you meant by 'infinite calls to the same block' but I did fill in the pieces from my end.

Comment: I've updated the code with location block. Can you give a try now? You need to handle the /dir location directive.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks a bunch, URL looks correct now. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @AdamIrinaga If you think it works, appreciate if you can mark this the right answer :)